# Unable to compile my C file using gcc48

Tags: c, gcc, freebsd

I am trying to compile a few C programs on my new virtualBox with FreeBSD operating system.

I have installed the gcc48.

I am trying to compile this basic program (saved as hello.c):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/

#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
   printf("Hello");
}
```

I am running the following command in my terminal:

```
gcc48 -c hello.c -o hi
```

Upon entering this command, I get the following error:

```
hello.c:1:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #!
 #!/usr/local/bin/
  ^
```

I have confirmed that the bash directory is in the correct place by doing the following command:

```
find /* -iname "bash"
```

With the following results:

```
/usr/local/share/doc/bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/ports/shells/bash
```

Hence, I do not see why I am getting an invalid preprocessing directive error...

On a side note:

If I remove the #! line and compile, it compiles successfully, and outputs the file named "hi"

But, if I try to run this file with ./hi  -  I get the following error:

```
./hi: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: Don't add C++ tag for C questions! And what do you think the Shebang would be good for? What is gcc48? You mean gcc-4.8? Start with reading a C book.

Comment: Read the error message. It t4ells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @amdixon You people did no read my post at all! I have tried removing #! and I told you the error I got...

Comment: @John3136  OK, if it is so obvious how about you tell me how to fix it... you are very unhelpful.

Comment: `gcc48 -c hello.c -o hi` using the `-c` option compiles C files to object files (not binary executable). Try `gcc48 hello.c -o hi` . This is assuming you remove the erroneous line `#!/usr/local/bin/` from the C file.

Comment: @Olaf You clearly need to read a book on FreeBSD then.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I just tried that, and I get the exact same invalid preprocessing directive error...

Comment: `#!/usr/local/bin/` followed by `bash` would make sense when used in a shell script. In a c source code it does not make sense at all. So better take a deep breath and think about whom you need to pardon.

Comment: See my update, I am assuming you remove the erroneous line `#!/usr/local/bin/`  . That is not valid C. C files are not meant to be run as scripts. You must also remove the `-c` from your gcc48 command if you intend to create an executable called `hi`. With `-c`you are compiling your C file to an object file called `hi` . Object files generally use a `.o` suffix.

Comment: @Borovez: "You clearly need to read a book on FreeBSD then" tells the person adding a (wrong) Shebang to a C source code file... As it is not me having problems proves your claim wrong. The bash or any other shell has noting to do with C code.

Answer (score 2):

remove this line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/
```

this is for shell scripting not c

Comment: That is only part of the problem

Comment: Yes, I also need to compile without the -c

Answer (score -5):

Ok. Well MichaelPetch was the closest the answer, but @amdixon's idea played a part.

So, I removed the #! line, saved, and compiled using (excluding -c)
    gcc hello.c -o hi

This was successfully compiled.

And running with ./hi is also working...

Thanks...!

Comment: I think you owe @Olaf an apology. He is a very knowledgeable, and he was correct to suggest reading a "C" book, and was correct about the Shebang (#!). Asking him to read the FREEBSD manual would have been like asking the Pope to read the King Jame's bible. I'm making this comment if you intend to get help in the future. People providing help and assistance may not take kindly to that. Olaf is a volunteer. He doesn't get paid mega bucks to help.

Comment: @MichaelPetch King James, poor choice of bible for a pope to read :-)

Comment: @Michael Petch - I do not owe anybody an apology.... I thanked the people who were kind and responded nicely without sarcasm and arrogance and actually helped me with this SIMPLE problem. I have read a C book, and I can program in C, I am just used to using GUI compilers and not command line.